# move imageView in xml

Tags: android

in my app I have this layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dip"/>
```

in this way the app works, but if I want to put the imageview top the app crashes
For example:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dip"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>
```

and this is the logcat:

```
03-17 10:42:39.919: W/ApplicationPackageManager(18362): getCSCPackageItemText()
03-17 10:42:40.130: D/AndroidRuntime(18362): Shutting down VM
03-17 10:42:40.130: W/dalvikvm(18362): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41844da0)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362): Process: com.example.localinuovo, PID: 18362
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.localinuovo/com.example.localinuovo.Second}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at com.example.localinuovo.Second.onCreate(Second.java:28)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
03-17 10:42:40.130: E/AndroidRuntime(18362):    ... 11 more
```

I do not understand why the app crashes. can anyone help me?

Comment: clean and build your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the crash log.

```
ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
```

You are casting a text view to an image view..

If it was working before you moved it, then try cleaning and build the app, so the .R file is regenerated. Else check you are using the right IDs and types.

E.g.

```
 (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried them both and my app is still working fine in both the views...I hope you are failing to have them under a base Layout (Linear or Relative).

Your 1st layout under "linear Layout":

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your 2nd layout under "linear Layout":

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I Guess the problem is not with the layout you have created, but with the java code in which you are trying to cast a TextView to a Widget according to the logcat output.